# HTML Hamburger - how to form proper X

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build an animated hamburger using css. To do so I use three different `span` and animate on click - nothing special.

**But somehow the transform-origin whatsoever is messed up, hence I can't form a proper `X`.** How can I do so?

```js
let active = false;

const handleNav = () => {
  const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
  if (!active) {
    hamburger.classList.add("is-active");
  } else {
    hamburger.classList.remove("is-active");
  }
  
  active = !active;
}
```

```css
.hamburger {
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

span:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.is-active span:first-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 0;
}

.is-active span:last-child {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger" onclick="handleNav()">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: You'll need to set their transform-origin in the right spot.

Comment: @Bergi And where?

Comment: Depends on where exactly you want them to end up. I guess the easiest would be to place it in the middle of the line (not left end), and not just rotate but also move it up by the 6px that separate it from the center of the icon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to hide the hamburger and display close icon.

Other way is to calculate the width required to make a perfect close icon and set width when active. Here width is around 17.
See the below code.

```js
let active = false;

const handleNav = () => {
  const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
  if (!active) {
    hamburger.classList.add("is-active");
  } else {
    hamburger.classList.remove("is-active");
  }
  
  active = !active;
}
```

```css
.hamburger {
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

span:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.is-active span:first-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 17px
}

.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 0;
}

.is-active span:last-child {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 17px
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger" onclick="handleNav()">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can make minor changes in design then change `height` and `margin-bottom` of `span`.

```
span{
    height: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
```

or slightly translate first and last bar:

```
.is-active span:first-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0,-3px);
}

.is-active span:last-child {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0,3px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you have to change `transform-origin` for the `<span>`s to the right value, here is a snippet:

```js
let active = false;

const handleNav = () => {
  const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
  if (!active) {
    hamburger.classList.add("is-active");
  } else {
    hamburger.classList.remove("is-active");
  }
  
  active = !active;
}
```

```css
.hamburger {
  width: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    transform-origin: 17%;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

span:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.is-active span:first-child {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.is-active span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 0;
}

.is-active span:last-child {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger" onclick="handleNav()">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```